# Using charts with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I'm trying to generate two charts using VBA. The problem is most examples use `ActiveChart` but I want multiple charts on multiple sheets. If I inserted a blank chart how do I rename that chart to reference it. I don't want a new chart to be generated each time I run the macro and I want it to be in the sheet. I'm struggling with the code but am assuming it will be something like the code below. I've attached the desired graph (I made this through excel, but I need to do it through VBA).

```
macro1()
lastrow2 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
dim chart1 as chart
dim chart2 as chart ' ect
chart1.title  = "test"
chart1.xaxis = sheet1.cell(lastrow2,1)
chart1.yaxis = "manhours"
end sub
```

[image]

using a the record function, i got the code commented below.  I tried to change it but i'm still having issues

```
Sub Macro7()

Dim Chart2 As ChartObject
Dim chartb As Chart
Chart2 = Sheet1.chartb.SeriesCollection(2)
chartb.Select
Formula = "=SERIES(Master!R3C3,Master!R4C1:R18C1,Master!R4C3:R19C3,2)"



'   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
 '  Selection.Formula =_ 
'"=SERIES(Master!R3C3,Master!R4C1:R18C1,Master!R4C3:R19C3,2)"

End Sub
```

I really just need this formula converted to i can reference my lastrow function and individual sheets

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
Selection.Formula =_ 
"SERIES(sheet1.cells(3,3),sheet1.cells(4,1):sheet1.cells(18,1)_
,sheet1.cells(4,3):sheet1.cells(4,19),2"
' Selection.Formula"_
' =SERIES(Master!R3C3,Master!R4C1:R18C1,Master!R4C3:R19C3,2)"
```

Comment: Are you asking about Chart sheets, or charts embedded on regular worksheets?

Comment: I wish to have chats embedded on the work sheet. As a run around i am pasting the values i want behind the graph. Then selecting that as by data value. But i would like to have it done all though VBA

Comment: Charts on a worksheet are contained in a `ChartObject` - the `Chart` property of this object is equivalent to the `ActiveChart` reference you typically see in recorded macros.  Try recording a macro while creating your chart, and start by editing the code you get from that.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It is absolutely possible and depends on what you want to do different approaches can be taken. Your question as is right now, is basically this: "Can we explicitly reference to a chart in vba?" and its answer is YES.

Comment: I tried using the record function but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

this was what i was trying to do. It declares the sheet name and references an existing chart named chart 1.

```
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim rng As Range

Set cht = Sheets("Master").ChartObjects("Chart 1")
Set rng = Sheets("Master").Range("A4", Range("D4").End(xlDown).Offset(-1))
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
cht.Chart.HasTitle = True
cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Bird Report - By Cost Code/Activity" ' title

cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Master!$B$3"
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Master!$C$3"
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=Master!$D$3"
```